# How to add numbers given by index of the list?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, addition

I have X_train which is [1000,2] and pos_list is the list of index which I need to add. That is, pos_list =[2,58,78,...] which denotes the rows of x_train which needs to be added together. Such that my sum_pos should be [1,2]

```
for i in range(len(pos_list)):
    sum_pos = sum(X_train(pos_list[i])
```

Comment: Best to include a small sample/example dataset in your question for other users to work on.

Answer (score 1):

So if I am getting this right, `X_train` is a matrix/table with 1000 rows and 2 columns and you need to add rows specified by `pos_list`. Your wording is super confusing but if I am understanding it right a solution like this may work:

```
X_train = ... # Our matrix
sum_pos = 0
for index in pos_list:
    sum_pos += sum(X_train[index])
```

OR a one line version (though not as pretty):

```
sum_pos = [sum(X_train[index]) for index in [pos for pos in pos_list]]
```